# pass array of observables to zip

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have an array of observables and want to pass to `Rx.Observable.zip`. I tried and it does not get subscribed at all.

Code snippet(just am example):

```
const sourceOne = Rx.Observable.of('Hello');
const sourceTwo = Rx.Observable.of('World!');
const sourceThree = Rx.Observable.of('Goodbye');
const sourceFour = Rx.Observable.of('World!');
const arr$ = [sourceOne, sourceTwo, sourceThree, sourceFour];

const zip$ = (a$) => Rx.Observable.zip(a$);

const subscribe = zip$(arr$).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Is there a way to pass an array to `Rx.Observable.zip`?

Comment: Would also be nice to know WHY this happens??? Why when THERE IS an overload that takes an array, it simply does nada! Very confusing and very time consuming to figure out...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Operator `zip` accepts only an unpacked array.

```
zip(sourceOne, sourceTwo, sourceThree, ...);
```

If you're using ES6 you can also use destructuring assignment with `...`:

```
const zip$ = (a$) => zip(...arr$);
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/tinaxeq/1/edit?js,console

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. No am I using javascript, is there anyway to do that too?

Comment: I checked the [ES6 spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and you can use `Rx.Observable.zip(...arr$);` as well. If you're using ES5 then use `Rx.Observable.zip(sourceOne, sourceTwo, sourceThree);`

Comment: If you are using ES5, you can use: `Rx.Observable.zip.apply(null, arr$);`

Comment: Just to note, ES6 is javascript. It's just a later version than you may be using e.g. ES5.